# How to access a password protected url with special character(backslash) in Java?

Tags: java

I'm trying to access a file on a server which is password protected which I've tried setting up a Password Authenticator to handle. However the username has a '\' character right in the middle of it. "foo\bar" which gives an error.
I just can't figure out how to encode the username.
I've tried the following: "foo\bar", "foo%5cbar", and "foo%92bar"

I'm hoping the problem is that I haven't encoded the name correctly, but it might be aproblem with my code. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Do you escape slash itself? "foo\\bar"

Comment: I did, but I realize I had to escape that one as well (weird imo). Finally go it working thanks. Now I just need to figure out why I can download text and images from the site with that authentication, but larger files like 3 meg zips still aren't working.